How to pass HTML form data to Flutter App (Android/IOS)?
How can i pass a data from an html form to an Flutter app..
This is an basic html form. I need to pass the values from this to a Flutter app.. How can i do that? For an example, consider a pwa. where the form (or login) would be from html and the other operations would be on Flutter (Android/ iOS). For now i want the data on to this for to be displayed upon flutter mobile app Is there any way to achieve this?!


If the form is rendered in a platform WebView then its data will have to be sent to a server (which can be your server). The server then notifies the app (via Firebase Cloud Messaging, for example) or the app queries the server. You will need a persistent id across these messages so you can link them.
If you don't own the server that this form sends its data to, then for security reasons you cannot intercept this in a Flutter app.

Its not possible to achieve this right?! without server?!

No, because if you don't own the server that this web pages sends its form data to, then you would be intercepting traffic from a web page to a server, and that is obviously not secure and therefore not possible.

You should make your Form in Flutter and use TextEditingCotroller for getting the values from the text fields..

The form is in html, not on Flutter.. Consider reading first?

Well you can make also form in Flutter using TextField widget and some of the buttons..

that's not the purpose though..

Tell me then what is your purpose.. I don't know if you know that, in Flutter you can write backend code and also frontend (UI).
